# SSAS PowerPivot MDX Problems w/ Measures Format_string

Tags: format, ssas, mdx

I am investigating a problem about **Calculated Measures** format issue from an OLAP Cube.

**I get these numbers :**

[image]

I am using this **mdx request**:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Ristournable Format] AS [Measures].[Ristournable], FORMAT_STRING = 'Currency'
SELECT 
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Ristournable Format] } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY { ([Affaire].[Affaire].[Affaire].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS
FROM [CUBE]
```

But it doesn't work. I think the problem comes from the `"."` instand of `","` for the numbers so my **MDX request** is using it as `String`. That's why I tried to force the numeric conversion with the first sentence `"WITH MEMBER ..."`. Unfortunately this doesn't work either.

Could you please help me to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `FORMAT_STRING='$##0.00'` or some other explicit way of telling MDX exactly what you want, rather than just passing 'Currency'?